Spring MQTT Integration shared subscritopn is not working
@Bean
public ClientManager<IMqttAsyncClient, MqttConnectionOptions> clientManager() {
    MqttConnectionOptions connectionOptions = new MqttConnectionOptions();
    connectionOptions.setServerURIs(new String[]{mqttProperties.getUrl()});
    connectionOptions.
            setConnectionTimeout(30);
    connectionOptions.
            setMaxReconnectDelay(30);
    connectionOptions.setUserName(mqttProperties.getUsername());
    connectionOptions.setPassword(mqttProperties
            .getPassword()
            .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    );
    connectionOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
    Mqttv5ClientManager clientManager =
            new Mqttv5ClientManager(
                    connectionOptions,
                    Objects.requireNonNull(MyUtils.getClientId()));
    clientManager.setPersistence(new MemoryPersistence());
    return clientManager;
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mqttInFlow(
        final ClientManager<IMqttAsyncClient, MqttConnectionOptions> clientManager) {
    Mqttv5PahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter messageProducer =
            new Mqttv5PahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                    clientManager, "$share/group1/test");

    messageProducer.setPayloadType(byte[].class);
    messageProducer.setManualAcks(true);
    messageProducer.setMessageConverter(new ByteArrayMessageConverter());

    return IntegrationFlow.from(messageProducer)
            .handle(mqttMessageHandler)
            .get();


}


public class MqttMessageHandler implements GenericHandler<byte[]> {

    @Override
    public Object handle(final byte[] payload, final MessageHeaders headers) {
        log.info("Received message: {}", payload);
        
    }
}

Given:
Above will subscribe to shared topic "$share/group1/test"
Expectation:
message(s) published to "test" should be available in MqttMessageHandler handle method to use.
Note: It's working for non-shared topic subscription.
Similar Question: Shared Subscription with Spring Integration Mqttv5 not Receiving Messages

is there any alternate solution or any workaround  to it?

Here is the link to spring-docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/mqtt.html

Apparently it does not work with shared client. Or Paho library has some restrictions when same clientId is used from publisher and subscriber to the shared subscription. Or something else.
When I use different clientId for publisher and subscriber, it works as expected: https://github.com/artembilan/sandbox/tree/master/spring-integration-mqtt-share-demo
UPDATE
OK. I see what is going on.
We use this API:
this.mqttClient.subscribe(new MqttSubscription[] {subscription},
                            null, null, this::messageArrived, subscriptionProperties)

And that one is used like:
this.comms.setMessageListener(subId, subscription.getTopic(), messageListener);

Where in case of shared we do have that $share/group1/test.
I logs I see this:
subscriber-for-shared-subscription: received key=0 message=MqttPublish [, qos=0, retained=false, duplicate=false, topic=test, payload=[hex=746573742064617461, utf8=test data, length=9], properties=MqttProperties [validProperties=[1, 2, 35, 8, 9, 38, 3, 126, 11]]

Pay attention to that topic=test.
So, apparently our listener for the $share/group1/test is not selected because received package has just topic.
The messageArrived() callback is called in case of non-manager via regular this.mqttClient.setCallback(this);.
Sounds like a bug on Eclipse Paho client library: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/965

Even with different ClientId its not working. I tried your demo code it worked, but when ClientManager is used to initalize Mqttv5PahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter it didn't worked. Spring docs example uses ClientManager to initialize Mqttv5PahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter. Here is the link https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/mqtt.html

Application used for just subscribing, and MQTTX tool is used to publish the message.

Yeah... Agree. I see it failing with the ClientManager. Not sure what is going on yet, but apparently as a workaround we have to use url and clientId on the channel adapter for now...

See an UPDATE in my answer.

As of now your demo code worked well with shared subscription. Just for info, MqttConnectionOptions also can be used to initialize Mqttv5PahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter in place of url, if MQTT Broker is configured with username/password.

Artem Bilan, Thanks for your help.

Sure thing! I'm aware of the Mqttv5PahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter functionality because I developed it.
